# sIFR server requests

Tags: sifr

Is there a way to reduce the number of times sIFR 3 requests the sifr.swf file from the server? I have tried using prefetch() without success. Is there a way cache the .swf file?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best explanation for pre-fetch is at [sifr3 - prefetch not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759398/sifr3-prefetch-not-working/764104#764104). So basically, the answer is yes, but it may not always work.

(`prefetch()` has been removed in more 'recent' nightlies, by the way.)